# Can we say "there should be any problem"?

Tags: american-english, north-american-english

Is this a proper sentence? "there should be any problem"    I know we can say "there shouldnt be any problem"  But can we say "there should be any problem" ?

Comment: Relevant:[Can I say “I'm glad I was of any help”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210235), [Does it sound weird to say “ I hope I can be of any use (help) to you” in a cover letter?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9830),  [Explain something: anything](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174473)

Comment: what? ı dont understand what u said?   All Im asking is " There should be any problem" is this a proper sentence?

Comment: Questions of the form "is this a proper sentence" are not allowed on this site. You need to ask about some grammatical feature or word in the sentence. Since you haven't specified, I'm assuming you're mainly unsure about the use of the word *any.* So, I posted some links to other questions about the word *any.* If you are mainly concerned about another part of the sentence, please edit your question to specify this.

Comment: why is it an affirmative example?  because it says "should"?

Comment: No: determinative "any" when used this way is restricted to non-affirmative contexts like _There aren't any problems_,  Your example is an affirmative one, so "any" is not possible, and in this instance it yields an ungrammatical sentence.

Comment: No, because it's a positive sentence, not a negative one.

Comment: if it said "there shouldnt be any problem" it would have been a negative sentence tho right???

Comment: Yes, it lacks a positive meaning; it's non-affirmative, so "any" works fine.

Comment: The wording  "there should be any problem" can meaningfully appear as part of a longer "if" phrase: "If there should be any problem with the WaxMaster, call our tech support hotline." Because your question presents the wording in all-lowercase letters, it's impossible to tell whether you're asking if the sentence "There should be any problem" makes sense (it doesn't) or if the phrase  "there should be any problem" can appear in a grammatically correct and meaningful sentence (it can).

Comment: @Sven Yargs Your expanded _if_ example is also non-affirmative, and hence "any" is grammatically okay. That's the crucial point about "any" when used this way. Substituting "some" (which has a positive orientation) for "any" gives the grammatically okay _There should be **some** problems_.

Comment: As John Lawler points out in [this question closed as General Reference](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/174481/2637), ***Any** is a **Negative Polarity** Item, and thus requires a negative context.* It's ***still*** General Reference for ELU (but would be fine on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You've repeated what I said about polarity. I think the OP understands it now.

Comment: @BillJ: I didn't read most of the comments in full - after the first few I just did a search for the specific word ***polarity*** (first here, which found nothing, then across the whole site) because I knew I'd easily find one of several places where John Lawler made that point. I was actually thinking in terms of closevoting as a duplicate, but when I realised the first one I'd found was already closed, I just voted the same way here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I say "I'm glad I was of any help"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210235/can-i-say-im-glad-i-was-of-any-help)

Answer (score 0):

No, this does not make any sense at all. You should phrase it as, "there could be a problem". This encapsulates the ideas that there could be some problem, and that of an unknown variety (replacing the use of *any*).

Comment: Yes, but you've omitted the crucial aspect of 'orientation'. "Any" in the sense we're discussing here is restricted to non-affirmative contexts. Which is why the OP's first example is ungrammatical, but his second one is okay. It's important to bring out that point.