# The multiple meanings of "any" in different circumstances

Tags: quantifiers, negative-polarity-items, negative-concord

I am confused about the different usages of the word (any* depending on the particular circumstance, and would appreciate some clarification. For instance, if I make the statement

1. I have more chocolate than any of you.

I would be implying that I have more chocolate than *each* and *every one* of you.

However, if I were to instead ask

2. Is there any of you with more chocolate than me?

I would be asking if *even one* of you has more chocolate than me.

Is it just the fact that I have phrased it as a question which makes the connotation different? Put differently, is there a systematic way to distinguish between the even one vs every one usage of *any*?

Comment: Could you explain what you don't understand about the meanings [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/any) ...?

Comment: I guess the dictionary meaning, "some" or "the smallest amount of" does not seem to correspond to any used in 1. above, which implies each, or every one..It is as if any is being used for both either one of you or every one of you...

Comment: "Either" is only applicable to two people or things. 'Any' can mean 'one of or each of' more than two.

Comment: Ah this is exactly my dilemma- one of is very different from each of. "One of" requires only one entity to satisfy a condition, whereas each of requires all. Is the meaning to be inferred from the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to know about *any* is that it's a [Negative Polarity Item](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/313482/15299). That means it's got weird grammar and semantics, and is part of a lot of idioms, so one can't make assumptions about what it means. [Negation is extremely complex.](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf)

The second thing to know about *any* is that it's a Quantifier, and works like other quantifiers in some ways. It doesn't do Q-Float, like *each* or *all* do:

- *Each/All of the boys passed = The boys each/all passed.*
- *Did all of the boys pass? = Did the boys all pass?*
- *Did any of the boys pass?*, but not **Did the boys any pass?*

And it alternates with *some*, and -- to the extent it has ***any*** meaning, which is not very much -- *any* has the same meaning as *some*, which is also a quantifier, but is **not** a negative polarity item and therefore can occur anywhere:

- *I saw some people coming this way*, but not **I saw any people coming this way.*
- *He insisted I drink some wine,* but not **He insisted I drink any wine*.

even when *any* would be allowed, as in a question:

- *Have you had something to eat yet? ~ Have you had anything to eat yet?*

There is no difference between these two questions, although some speakers and addressees may have their own conventions for using them -- and any associated intonations.

As for the examples in the question:

- *I have more chocolate than any of you.*

is a use of *any* in the negative context of the baseline for a comparative construction (identified by *than*, which occurs only in comparatives, and therefore marks negation).

The second example is ungrammatical, as noted. Corrected, it would be

- *Are there any of you with more chocolate than me?*

which is a use of *any* in the negative environment of a question, like the *some/any* example above.

As soon as you notice that negatives keep popping up in example sentences, your first thought should be that there's [an NPI](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/NPIs.pdf) involved.

Comment: Great answer!! I will be sure to read it in detail.